# Sending String/Word/Characters through /dev/ttyS0 (RS232)

Tags: command-line, c, serial-port

I am trying to send a string to the Serial Comm Port /dev/ttyS0 .  On a Windows  machine I use Turbo Basic program which has been working for many years.  I can send '*80' and it turns on a light on my remote Micro.  I can send '*81' to turn it off and so on.  How do I 'send' these strings in either 'C' or the 'bash' shell?  I have added the user to the 'dialout' group so it can be run without having 'root' access.

The communication settings are 2400 N 8 1 and that has been set and flow control is off. That is what is required by the attached Micro.

Comment: Were any special settings required for the serial (bits, speed)?

Answer (score 3):

If the serial port settings are correct, then it's as easy as

```
echo '*80' >/dev/ttyS0
```

provided that you have permission to write to the device file. If the device doesn't want a newline after the command, use `echo -n '*80' >/dev/ttyS0`.

If you need to change the serial port settings, you can use [`setserial`](http://setserial.sourceforge.net/). Or alternatively you can use one of the many programs that can interact with a serial port, for example

```
screen /dev/ttyS0 2400,cs8,-ixon,-ixoff
```

and then type `*80`, or use [minicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) or [microcom](https://github.com/Oliviers-OSS/microcom) or …

Comment: I tried echo '*80' > /dev/ttyS0 and nothing happened.  Do I have to add something to the Kernel and how do I tell if the Comm port is setup in all ways to accept direct input such as '*80' > /dev/ttyS0 ?

Comment: @robertdaleweir Usually, if nothing happens, it's because the serial port settings are not the same on both ends. How did you set up the serial port on Linux? Try a program such as Screen that explicitly sets the serial port speed when it starts, or a program such as Minicom that has menus for this.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux or BSD would have a `minicom` package available, which is *the* toolbox talking to serial devices.